# how to display error message  when gps or wi-fi is off in android device

Tags: android

i created application for showing location and latitude,longitude for where am i? but gps or wi -fi is off the application is crashed. how to prevent this crash by showing corresponding error. i want to show error message in android device. Log.e() is not shown in device how to do that. please correct me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your application crashes you should first look for the reason (mostly an exception) then catch this exception and throw out a readable error message (a dialog or something).

What's causing the crash?

Comment: it works well when wi -fi, gps is in on stage. for checking i turn off the wi -fi ,gps in android device it crashed. instead crash i want to show a alert message. crash message is " this application map application is(process.net.learn.maps) has stopped unexpectedly.

Comment: well you have to check out the exact reason via e.g. logcat (in eclipse) or any other software capable of reading your device logs.